# Enumerating default UWP ThemeResources

Tags: .net, uwp

I would like to get a list of the keys and values from the light and dark theme resources under UWP. Does anyone know where these can be found?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187274.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn518235.aspx

Comment: @JustinXL: That's just what I'm looking for - could you add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I will, but I think the links are still missing a few resources. I will see if I can find them n get back to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find all **24** *system colors* [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187274.aspx). Also there are *system high-contrast colors* on the same page as well as a special `SystemAccentColor`

> At runtime, this resource (`SystemAccentColor`) gets the color that the user has specified
>   as the accent color in the Windows personalization settings.

Almost all the *system brushes* are defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn518235.aspx). Do take note that this link is based on Windows 8.1 and it's missing a few `Brushes` like `PivotForegroundThemeBrush`.

How do I know? This is how I find all the *system colors/brushes* -

**Colors -** *Properties > Brush > Solid color brush > Color resources*
[image]

**Brushes** *Properties > Brush > Brush resources*
[image]

Hope this helps!