# Semi Transparent Background in UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, uwp, background-color, uwp-xaml

i want to use Semi Transparent Background in List Box
i was using `Background="{StaticResource PhoneSemitransparentBrush}"`
in windows phone 8 apps. 
But this semitransparent brush is not available in UWP, any alternate brush for same semi transparent background in UWP ?

Comment: Why can't you just create your own resource? If you want a system defined one, check my my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320976/enumerating-default-uwp-themeresources), and you really should be using ThemeResource instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closet you can get is probably from `SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumBrush` which uses `SystemAltMediumColor` which has an alpha channel of 60% where the phone brush has of 66.7%.

Comment: Thanks , your answer is also helped me

Comment: SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush working perfect, very very similar to windows phone 8 semi transparent brush

Answer (score 4):

#### Method 1:

Setting `Opacity` for background color

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </ListView.Background>
</ListView>
```

#### Method 2:

By setting Alpha channel for your background color

```
<ListView Background="#7FFF0000"/>
```

You can choose Color with Alpha channel in Properties Panel

Properties Panel > Brush > Background > Solid color brush > In that you can set Transparency by setting `A`.

Comment: in my case i just use white in color and opacity is 0.55. thanks